# ～するもの　vs　～すること grammar difference N3

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I'm studying for taking the JLPT N3 and I've run across this exercise:

> この用紙は必ず黒か青のペンで記入する（_____）

Between the possible answers I had these two: もの and こと.
I chose もの but the correct answer is こと.

Could anyone help me try to understand what's the difference, in this case, between this two?

---

So I did a little bit more research and I found this:

Verb + ことだ indicates essential ACTIONS.
Verb + ものだ indicates ideal and essential STATES.

So with this I pretty much understand the exercise but still, is there anything else I should pay attention to?